# what's the point of this short story?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> She recognized the writing on the envelope immediately. The Gypsy had
>   warned her that she had no future with this man, yet here he was –
>   five lonely years after their last meeting, begging her to join him in
>   New York.
>
> She felt unbelievably happy as she stepped on board the
>   Titanic.

I know all of the word and phrases but I can't figure out the whole meaning?

Comment: That's simple, read it sentence by sentence and you'll get it. Only the first sentence about the writing and the envelope needs more context.

Comment: The Gypsy sometime ago told the young woman that she has no future with this particular man. Nevertheless, the young girl decides to board the ship "titanic" to reach him in New York on invitation in the envelop. Of course the prophecy is fulfilled because we all know Titanic sunk in 1912.

Comment: @SovereignSun no context. It's a short story.It has to have a point which I don't get.

Comment: On my own screen, it looks like maybe 10 point.

Comment: @MK What month and day was it when it sunk?

Comment: The wisdom can be something like "A person often meets his destiny on the road he took to avoid it." - Jean de La Fontaine

Comment: April 15th I believe.

Comment: @MK, I hadn't recognized the coincidence.  Our personal finances sink on the anniversary of the Titanic sinking (Taxes due day).

Comment: -1 because you have quoted someone else's work (a short story) and not provided any attribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gypsy sometime ago told the young woman that she has no future with this particular man. Nevertheless, the young girl decides to board the ship "titanic" to reach him in New York on invitation in the envelop. Of course the prophecy is fulfilled because we all know Titanic sunk in 1912.

The wisdom can be something like "A person often meets his destiny on the road he took to avoid it." - Jean de La Fontaine

Very short stories generally presuppose the reader knows the context.

Comment: Titanic is capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

The idiom **to have a future with {someone}** means "to thrive or succeed with that person (as  partner, spouse, associate, employer, or whatever)" not merely "to encounter the person in the future".

> I'm afraid, Mr Jones, that you have no future with Acme Widgets. You
>   couldn't sell a life-vest to a drowning man.
>
> Don't marry her. She's selfish, lazy, spoiled, greedy, and overuses commas. You two have no future together.